# Is there a way to make an ID column autoincrement starting with zero

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to create ID primary key column with autoincrement which starts with zero.How do i write a query for it?

Comment: what about autoincrement ?

Comment: But i want it to start from zero instead of one.

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve with an id starting from zero? It can be done, yes, but it just complicates things and I don't see any value there.

Comment: One way to do it - explicitly insert the value 0 for primary key into the table.